# Where are Collections stored from Geometry Nodes?

Tags: materials, add-on, geometry-nodes, collections, outliner

i am trying to find a Collection that is used from my Geometry Nodes (Collection Info), but it is not shown in the outliner. Where is it stored? Added by an Add-on

Comment: AFAIK the collection must be stored in the same blender file as you are working in, for -> so it must one of collections or sub-collections in the outliner. You just need to find it. Or the nodes might be trying to link to a collection that doesn't exist in which case the output of collection info node should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collection hasn't been linked to your current scene, you can find it in the *Blender File* view of the outliner.

Click on the second button from the left in the top left corner of the outliner, choose *Blender File* and navigate to the collections container, and you should find your collection there. Then you can either instance the collection in the scene or link the collection to the scene from there using the right-click context menu. Go back to the regular *View Layer* mode afterwards.

[image]